# Does SQL 2008 Express supports Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express, change-tracking

Due to the lack of documentation for this on MSDN, I am forced to ask here.

Does the Express version support the same Change Tracking Feature(s) as the other editions does?

Thanks

leppie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, talked too fast, here is the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Under the **Replication** section.

Comment: that link is no longer relevant - after more searching I found the answer is yes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx